# High velocity streaming data enrichment with low velocity/slow changing data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

My system consists of

- High velocity telemetry data generated by IoT devices.
- Relatively static/slow changing reference/lookup data - Alarm Rules

Each IoT device has 0 to 1 Alarm Rules. An Alarm Rule has average size of 1-2 KB.

Most Alarm Rules, once set, stay the same for weeks, months, or even a year or more.

Eventual consistency of Alarm Rules is also acceptable - if Alarm Rule is edited, it is acceptable for it to take effect in 15-30 minutes.

**Question** - What would be the best approach to enrich device telemetry stream with alarm rules?

**Option 1** - [RichAsyncFunction](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/#async-io-api) + in memory cache

Each time I receive a telemetry message from device, I execute RichAsyncFunction. It first checks if in memory cache has Alarm Rule. If no Alarm Rule is not found in cache, a request is sent to database. Cache items expire in 30 minutes.

**Option 2** - [KeyedProcessFunction](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/#the-processfunction) + state object

Same logic as with option 1. Except instead of using in memory cache, I store Alarm Rule for each IoT device into ValueState<> and periodically refresh it using *ctx.timerService().register...* scheduler (**what happens if this gets called multiple times? will onTimer function also get triggered multiple times or just once?**).

**Option 3** - [CoProcessFunction](https://github.com/knaufk/enrichments-with-flink/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/knaufk/enrichments/streams/ProcessingTimeJoin.java)/KeyedCoProcessFunction + 2 streams, one for telemetry, second for alarms

This option offers the highest throughput and lowest latency. I would consume Kafka Topic for alarm rules and update ValueState<> with the stream data.

What's stopping me from implementing this solution is Kafka Topic message retention time. By default Kafka messages have 7 day retention time.

If I have alarm rule A for device B, and I send it to Kafka Topic, if the alarm rule A does not change over the next 7 days, the alarm rule will no longer be visible on 8th day. Basically, on 8th day, when consuming messages from device B, the system won't see any device alarm rules.

I could increase retention time to longer period, but that does not seem like a reasonable time. Alternative would be external service that periodically emits all alarm rules to Kafka topic, say, every 6-7 days.

Comment: You seem to be assuming the the ground truth for the rules must live outside of Flink. Why not keep the rule state in Flink (permanently)?

Comment: Wouldn't that still require the initial state and future updates to come from Kafka topic/sql database/external service? Or is it possible for my services (for example REST API) to "directly" talk to Flink and insert/update/delete state?

Comment: I would still use Kafka to decouple the external service from Flink, but the 7-day retention interval doesn't have to be a blocker, if you're willing to rely on checkpoints or savepoints to preserve the rules.